# MVC authentication failing after deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC application that uses password field to authenticate users. Locally it works as intended and the workflow proceeds to the next step. When I deploy the code in IIS server I am unable to make the password feature work. The connection string with database is working as I am able to save the data to the database.
I have added sample code.

```
    public ActionResult Authenticate(string password)
    {
        try
        {
            IdentityTheftEntities context = new IdentityTheftEntities();
            Admin user = context.Admins.Where(x => x.Password == password && x.IsActive == true).FirstOrDefault();
            if (user != null)
            {
                Session.Add("userID", user.ID);
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.errorMessage = "Please put correct password!";
                return View("requests");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            ViewBag.errMes = ex.Message.ToString();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("requests", "home"); ;
    }
```

Checking the validity by `@if (Session["userID"] != null)`.
When I enter the password and hit submit nothing happens.

Comment: `"nothing happens"` - If the form isn't being submitted at all then that sounds like a problem with client-side code, not server-side code.

Comment: @David - why would the code work locally if that was the case? The issue arises only when it is deployed.

Comment: There could be some other root cause which is modifying the client-side code.  But the point remains.  If the form isn't posting at all then this server-side code is *never even invoked*.  So clearly it can't be the culprit.  You first need to find where the code is failing before you can even begin to correct it.

Comment: Try to run your project in release mode, it could be a javascript issue as the bundles will be minified under release mode. If you have any javascript bugs/issues your code might not work correctly but could work in debug as bundles are separated.

Comment: After removing the admin table from edmx file and updating the edmx file solved the problem.